# Запуск Python скрипта автоматически перед запуском приложения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть скрипт, который меняет конфиг приложения.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы этот скрипт запускался автоматически, когда я запускаю приложение?
Если можно, пожалуйста, напишите как.

Comment: Смотря что за приложение) И приложение ,как я понял обычный PE?

Comment: Это игра, в которой я меняю конфиг с помощью скрипта
Было бы великолепно, если он запускался сразу вместе с игрой.

Comment: сделайте еще один скрипт из которого запускаете целевой скрипт и потом приложение

Comment: A может вставить его в начало приложения?

Comment: Может лучше сделать скрип который "сначала" будет менять конфиг(при условии что конфиг надо поменять один раз за сеанс), а потом запускать приложение, и при желании из него(скрипта) можно сделать экзешник. Типо когда хочешь запустить игру запускаешь скрипт.

Comment: Я сделал через модуль ```os```, просто запускал игру после своего основного скрипта)
Всем большое спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть 2 пути, которые мне известны:

1. Вы можете поменять скрипт игры, чтобы он сначала запускал ваш скрипт, затем свой. Обычно игры зашифрованы, что делает этот путь трудноватым.
2. Вы можете встроить в свой скрипт открытие игры. Например, используя тот же модуль `os`:

```
    {Ваш код}
    import os
    os.system('start {путь к файлу с самим файлом}')
```